# Check if the submodule commit is the same as what the repo points to

Tags: git, git-submodules

We're using git submodules to manage a large projects. We have around 20 submodules inside this large project and the submodules don't get updated often.

Before executing a `git submodule update` command which tells git to check out the commit already specified in the index of the superproject, I want to check if the commit exist in the submodule?

Something like `git branch --contains $SHA` but for submodules.

If it doesn't exist then I would like to do a `git fetch` inside the submodule which doesn't containt the commit or `git submodule foreach git pull`

Ideally I would like to avoid doing `git submodule foreach git pull` for all the 20 submodules and do a git fetch if the submodule commit is different from what the repo points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git submodule foreach --quiet \
'git branch --contains <sha1> 2>/dev/null || echo $(basename $(pwd)) no such commit'
```

Will print the information about current commit if it is in current branch ( or rather in current tree ) and print that there's no such commit otherwise ( the part after `||`).

Part after `||` can be used to run git fetch instead of priniting the information.

Comment: This is awesome thanks. One last questions, do you know the best way to get the submodule commit the parent repo points to? I was able to do this using `git rev-parse <BRANCH NAME>^{commit}:< PATH TO SUBMODULE>`

Comment: i.e. The commit I should check for if its present in the submodule before doing a fetch.

Comment: run `git submodule update` then run `git submodule status`. Status will return all the submodule's sha1s that are currently pinned to master repo.